# How is a Euclidean space a function space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

To be more precise, in what sense is $\mathbb R^N$ a function space?

I quote from page number 3, in the first chapter of "Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications" by Debnath and Mikusinski

"Note that spaces $\mathbb R^N$ and $\mathbb C^N$ can be defined as function spaces: $\mathbb R^N$ is the space of all real valued functions defined on $\{1,\dots ,N\}$ ..."

Could somebody please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

The vector $v=(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be seen as the function $v: \{1,2,3\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f(1) = a$, $f(2)=b$, $f(3)=c$

Comment: This is somewhat redundant compared to my answer.

Comment: And both were posted at the same time...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my answer was there before. Like a 100% sure!

Answer (score 1):

Define $f \colon \mathrm{Map}(\{ 1, \dotsc ,N \},\mathbb{R},) \to \mathbb{R}^N$ by $f(g)=(g(1),g(2),\dotsc ,g(N))$. This gives you the desired isomorphism. 
This is basically the choice of a basis.